# What is meant by the following regex?

Tags: regex, perl

I am working on kernel module and the module outputs a hex code which is being read by a perl script using regex.

I am not able to make sense out of it:

```
while (<>) {
    s/^([a-fA-F0-9]+)(\.)([a-fA-F0-9]+)(\s+.*)/sprintf("%s%s%s%s",  &$converter(hex($1)), $2, hex($3), $4)/oe;
} continue {
    print;
}
```

We are trying to read hex code to time in nano second.

Comment: regex101 can answer questions like this one. https://regex101.com/r/wvt1vK/1 See the "Explanation" tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s/^([a-fA-F0-9]+)(\.)([a-fA-F0-9]+)(\s+.*)/sprintf("%s%s%s%s",  &$converter(hex($1)), $2, hex($3), $4)/oe;
```

There are 4 capturing groups, each is covered by brackets ():

`$1 -> ([a-fA-F0-9]+)`

`$2 ->  (\.)`

`$3 -> ([a-fA-F0-9]+)`

`$4` -> `(\s+.*)`

[Details here](https://regex101.com/r/xhEq1j/5)